# Cannot get socket.io to work with my Node.js/React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am having trouble trying to combine my React/Node.JS app with socket.io.

This is what I have for my client side:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import RightContent from "./components/RightContent";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import splashImage from "./img/splash.png";
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

function CodenamesClone(props) {

    React.useEffect(() => {
          document.title = props.title; // eslint-disable-next-line
          
    }, []); 

    
    socket.on('connect', ()=>{
        console.log("Connected");
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("testback", (data) => {
            console.log(data);
        })
    }, [socket]);
    
    function sayHello(){
        console.log(socket);
        socket.emit('test', "sajdhfadsjhfasodhfoisd sadhf jasdhfkjas dfkjsadhf skadjhf ");
    }
      
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Navbar />
            <div className="content" style={{backgroundImage: 'url('+splashImage+')'}}>
                <div className="left-content">
                    <div className="left-box">
                        <div className="main-header" style={{padding:'0 0 55px 0px'}}>Codenames Clone</div>
                        <div className="main-body main-space-even" style={{paddingBottom: '20px'}}>                            
                            <button onClick={sayHello}>Default</button>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <RightContent />
            </div>
        </div>
      );
}

export default CodenamesClone;
```

And this is what I have for my server code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`User Connected: ${socket.id}`);

  socket.on("test", (data) => {
    socket.to(data.room).emit("testback", data);
  });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("SERVER IS RUNNING");
});
```

Any help would be great! Thank you!

I am not too versed in backend so I am not too sure where else to go from here. I followed a bunch of tutorials, but I can't seem to get it to connect.